# AWS Codedeploy terminated EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

we have an AWS EC2 instance deployed in an Elastic beanstalk environment which is updated via Codedeploy. This EC2 instance has a number of other services installed over & above that deployed via Codedeploy.

This was all working fine until today when Codedeploy terminated the EC2 instance and started a new one. This of course caused us to lose all other services.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You mean that installed other services in an EB managed instance? This something that you shouldn't do. These are managed instances. EB will stop and create new instances as needed.